# Automate git pull with ssh authentication via a script (non-interactive)

Tags: ssh, git

I have a bunch of raspberry pis running Ubuntu 20.04 server, that I wish to update automatically via Git, non-interactively.

The script does the following:

```bsh
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" ; ssh-add /home/michael/.ssh/terminal_github_deploy_key ; git -C /home/michael/terminal/src pull
```

The script is actually in Python, but does the equivalent to above:

```py
cmds = []
cmds.append('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"')
cmds.append(f'ssh-add {HOME_DPATH}/.ssh/terminal_github_deploy_key')
cmds.append(f'git -C {CHECKOUT_DPATH} pull')
cmd = ' ; '.join(cmds)
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

It works fine except it raises this interactive warning:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

According to research it deliberately does not accept pipes for security reasons (so `yes | ...` does not work). I am not sure what is raising the warning, I am guessing it's SSH, being called by Git, but not sure how to ignore it? I don't have to use `ssh-add` but that was the way I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without writing another script in something like [expect](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/), you will not be able to do that while being *vanilla*.

> The easiest way to do so is to add the [Github Host Keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) to
> `.ssh/known_hosts`

EDIT: Due to the fact that there is a lot of servers, this is not possible, what is on that site is not individual host keys

Otherwise, you may be able to use [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to automate that

Comment: What is on that site is the _shared_ host key for all Github servers. You only need one known_hosts line to handle the entirety of Github.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Wieland's answer above but marginally better - rather than disabling script host key checking, you can request that SSH fetch the public key prior to attempting to connect:

```bsh
$ export MACHINE_IP=...
$ ssh-keyscan "$MACHINE_IP" | tee -a ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ ./path/to/script
```

This is how I have setup CICD workflows that require SSH access (e.g. Ansible). In that case, the IPs are static so I store then somewhere and have the CICD pipeline add them to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file prior to running the script.

I believe you could even use the FQDN rather than an IP address, but then you'd have to take care of any dynamic DNS behavior that may result in your host resolving to multiple IP addresses (either now or in the future)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable host key verification for SSH-through-git by setting `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`:

> This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts. If this flag is set to ''no'', ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files.

(from [ssh-config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)). If you call git like `git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' pull` the SSH command git will pass that flag to SSH.

Comment: This makes the SSH connections vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, essentially losing a lot of the security SSH offers. Probably not what you want.

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` is better; it will add new host keys but refuse to change existing ones. It still weakens security slightly but it's an improvement.

Comment: You'll want to put that option in the specific `Host` stanza for the relevant machines - not in `Host *`!